# Jquery скрыть часть таблицы

Tags: jquery

Есть таблица

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th><button class="btn-show-catalog-table">Сравнить тарифы каталога отрасли</button></th>
        <th>Какой-то текст</th>
        <th>Какой-то текст</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Какой-то текст</td>
            <td>Какой-то текст</td>
            <td>Какой-то текст</td>
        </tr>
        <div class="show-catalog-table">
            <tr>
                <td>Какой-то текст</td>
                <td>Какой-то текст</td>
                <td>Какой-то текст</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Какой-то текст</td>
                <td>Какой-то текст</td>
                <td>Какой-то текст</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Какой-то текст</td>
                <td>Какой-то текст</td>
                <td>Какой-то текст</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Какой-то текст</td>
                <td>Какой-то текст</td>
                <td>Какой-то текст</td>
            </tr>
        </div>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Пишу следующий код:

```
function toggleCatalogBlock($btn, $block) {
    $($btn).click(function() {
        $($block).slideToggle("slow");
    });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    toggleCatalogBlock(".btn-show-catalog-table", ".show-catalog-table");
});
```

Но со столбцами это не работает... Как сделать так, что они плавно скрывались по высоте?

Comment: Со строками не работает* ошибся

Comment: Получилось сделать, используя tbody 2 раза. Только вопрос, почему он резко пропадает и резко появляется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что браузер игнорирует любые дочерние теги внутри таблицы кроме `tr`, `tbody` и т.д. Поэтому правильнее будет добавить добавить класс, к элементу который вы хотите открывать/скрывать, а именно к `tr`

```js
function toggleCatalogBlock($btn, $block) {
  $($btn).click(function() {
    var $blocks = $($block)
    if ($blocks.is(':visible')) {
      $blocks = $($blocks.get().reverse());
    }
    toggleOne($blocks, 0);
  });
};

function toggleOne(blocks, index) {
  var block = blocks.eq(index);
  if (!block.length) return; 
  block.slideToggle(50, toggleOne.bind(null, blocks, index + 1));
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  toggleCatalogBlock(".btn-show-catalog-table", ".show-catalog-table");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th><button class="btn-show-catalog-table">Сравнить тарифы каталога отрасли</button></th>
    <th>Какой-то текст</th>
    <th>Какой-то текст</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Какой-то текст</td>
      <td>Какой-то текст</td>
      <td>Какой-то текст</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="show-catalog-table">
      <td>Какой-то текст</td>
      <td>Какой-то текст</td>
      <td>Какой-то текст</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="show-catalog-table">
      <td>Какой-то текст</td>
      <td>Какой-то текст</td>
      <td>Какой-то текст</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="show-catalog-table">
      <td>Какой-то текст</td>
      <td>Какой-то текст</td>
      <td>Какой-то текст</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="show-catalog-table">
      <td>Какой-то текст</td>
      <td>Какой-то текст</td>
      <td>Какой-то текст</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Так получается, что нельзя сделать так, чтобы они плавно скрывались по высоте?

Comment: @ВикторТюрин есть несколько способов, один из них можете посмотреть в моем обновленном ответе

Comment: Понял, щас буду разбираться! Спасибо большое)